# How to apply post redirect and get pattern in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, post-redirect-get

I am testing with a very simple application in node.js where I create and save an application. I show the post form with the newPost function and I receive the post with the data in the savePost method. In the latter one I do a validation (with iform module) and I want to go show again the same page as before but filling the form with the data sent by the user and also with the errors found.

I have a similar code like this one. In it I render the same jade page if I find any error. It works though I want to apply the pattern redirect and get there as I don't want to send again the post request when the user presses F5.

So, how is the usual way to make a post redirect and get from the post method passing them all the parameters I have received adding the errors? Is there any module which can help to do so?

```
var prepareObject = function(req, res){
    var errors = {};
    if('iform' in req){
        errors = req.iform.errors;
    }
    return {title: 'Nuevo Post', body:req.body, errors: errors};
};

// mapped as /newPost (type GET)
exports.newPost = function(req, res){
    //show form to create post
    res.render('newPost', prepareObject(req, res));
}

// mapped as /savePost (type POST)
exports.savePost = function(req, res){
    if(req.iform.errors) {
        //there are errors: show form again to correct errors
        res.render('newPost', prepareObject(req, res));
    }else{
        //no errors: show posts
        res.redirect('/posts');
    }   
}
```

Comment: @chovy I want an answer with doesn't rely on a special module. For example I would also like to apply Post-redirect-get without validation.

Comment: I believe PRG only applies to successful form submissions. When validation errors happen you can render a page.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect to GET "/newPost" instead of rendering the "newPost" template.
To have autocomplete working, you may either add the data to the redirect query (faster) and render it, or add the data to the session (don't forget to delete it after rendering), but the later option requires a session store.